# Checking if a string matches all characters but one of another string

Tags: java, string, list, loops, split

I have a list of strings and with each string I want to check it's characters against every other string to see if all it's characters are identical except for one.

For instance a check that would return true would be checking

rock against lock

clock and flock have one character that is different, no more no less.

rock against dent will obviously return false.

I have been thinking about first looping through the list and then having a secondary loop within that one to check the first string against the second.

And then using `split("");` to create two arrays containing the characters of each string and then checking the array elements against each other (i.e. comparing each string with the same position in the other array 1-1 2-2 etc...) and so long as only one character comparison fails then the check for those two strings is true.

Anyway I have a lot of strings (4029) and considering what I am thinking of implementing at the moment would contain 3 loops each within the other that would result in a cubic loop(?) which would take a long long time with that many elements wouldn't it?

Is there an easier way to do this? Or will this method actually work okay? Or -hopefully not- but is there some sort of potential logical flaw in the solution I have proposed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do it the naive way?

```
bool matchesAlmost(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1.length != str2.length)
        return false;
    int same = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i) {
        if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(i))
            same++;
    }
    return same == str1.length - 1;
}
```

Now you can just use a quadratic algorithm to check every string against every other.

Comment: Cheers, I like this way a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the length of two strings are equal

```
String str1 = "rock";
        String str2 = "lick";

        if( str1.length() != str2.length() )
            System.out.println( "failed");

        else{
            if( str2.contains( str1.substring( 0, str1.length()-1)) || str2.contains(  str1.substring(1, str1.length() )) ){
                System.out.println( "Success ");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println( "Failed");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What about `rock` and `rick`?

Comment: oops! I did not take that test case. The above one is good!! sorry for this!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach but this one works even when two strings are not of same length. For example : cat & cattp They differ by one character p and t is repeated. Looks like O(n) time solution using additional space for hashmap & character arrays.

```
/**
 * Returns true if two strings differ by one character
 * @param s1 input string1
 * @param s2 input string2
 * @return true if strings differ by one character 
 */
boolean checkIfTwoStringDifferByOne(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] c1, c2;

    if(s1.length() < s2.length()){
        c1 = s1.toCharArray();
        c2 = s2.toCharArray();
    }else{
        c1 = s2.toCharArray();
        c2 = s1.toCharArray();
    }

    HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++) {
        hs.add(c1[i]);
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < c2.length; j++) {
        if (! hs.contains(c2[j])) {
            count = count +1;
        }
    }

    if(count == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to concatenate strings together one forward and other one in reverse order. Then check in single loop for both ends matching chars and also start from middle towards ends matching char. If more than 2 chars mismatch break.

If one mismatch stop and wait for the next one to complete if it reaches the same position then it matches otherwise just return false.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    New1 x = new New1();
    x.setFunc();
}

static void setFunc() {
    Set s = new HashSet < Character > ();
    String input = " aecd";
    String input2 = "abcd";
    String input3 = new StringBuilder(input2).reverse().toString();
    String input4 = input.concat(input3);
    int length = input4.length();

    System.out.println(input4);
    int flag = 0;

    for (int i = 1, j = length - 1; j > i - 1; i++, j--) {

        if (input4.charAt(i) != input4.charAt(j)) {

            System.out.println(input4.charAt(i) + " doesnt match with " + input4.charAt(j));
            if (input4.charAt(i + 1) != input4.charAt(j)) {
                System.out.println(input4.charAt(i + 1) + " doesnt match  with " + input4.charAt(j));
                flag = 1;
                continue;
            } else if (input4.charAt(i) != input4.charAt(j - 1)) {
                System.out.println(input4.charAt(i) + " doesnt match with " + input4.charAt(j - 1));
                flag = 1;
                break;
            } else if (input4.charAt(i + 1) != input4.charAt(j - 1) && i + 1 <= j - 1) {
                System.out.println(input4.charAt(i + 1) + " doesnt match with xxx " + input4.charAt(j - 1));
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 0) {
        System.out.println("Strings differ by one place");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Strings does not match");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the strings have the same length, I think this would help:

```
public boolean differByOne(String source, String destination)
{
    int difference = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<source.length();i++)
    {
        if(source.charAt(i)!=destination.charAt(i))
        {
            difference++;

            if(difference>1)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return difference == 1;
}
```